# Is there a way to manipulate properties of a child of an href in a use tag?

Tags: html, svg

I have this code:

```
<use href="#hour10" x="120" y="0" />
<use href="#hour10" x="300" y="0" />
<use href="#hour10" x="420" y="0" />
<use href="#hour10" x="600" y="0" />
<use href="#hour10" x="720" y="0" />
    <g id="hour10" style="fill-rule:evenodd; stroke:#FFFFFF; stroke-width:0.25; stroke-opacity:1; stroke-linecap:butt; stroke-linejoin:miter;">
        <polygon id="a" points=" 10, 10  20, 0  80, 0  90, 10  80, 20  20, 20" fill="#FF0000"/>
        <polygon id="b" points=" 90, 10 100, 20 100, 80  90, 90  80, 80  80, 20" fill="#FF0000"/>
        <polygon id="c" points=" 90, 90 100,100 100,160  90,170  80,160  80,100" fill="#FF0000"/>
        <polygon id="d" points=" 90,170  80,180  20,180  10,170  20,160  80,160" fill="#FF0000"/>
        <polygon id="e" points=" 10,170  0,160  0,100  10, 90  20,100  20,160" fill="#FF0000"/>
        <polygon id="f" points=" 10, 90  0, 80  0, 20  10, 10  20, 20  20, 80" fill="#FF0000"/>
        <polygon id="g" points=" 10, 90  20, 80  80, 80  90, 90  80,100  20,100" fill="#FF0000"/>
```

And I want to be able to modify the fill of individual polygons within the "hour10", is it possible to do this for each instance within my 'use' calls? Or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Remove the fill attribute from the polygons. Give a either a fill attribute or a style to the use elements

Comment: @enxaneta I was able to figure this out, but can I use this to modify individual polygons within each use case? For example, in my css, #hour10 #a { fill: black;} doesn't seem to do anything, I'm guessing since 'use' forgets about the child structure of the original element? Or am I missing something? Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

`<use>` creates duplicated elements inside the shadow DOM. The shadow DOM is encapsulated from its parent [by design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) to create a way of preventing unwanted CSS style bleed. However, some CSS properties are permitted to "pierce" the shadow DOM; firstly that includes inherit. With this, you can get the whole digit to change colour:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="900px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 900 200" xml:space="preserve">

    <style type='text/css'>
     polygon {
       fill: inherit;
    }
    
    use {
        fill: red;
    }
    
    #digit1, #digit6 {
        fill: blue;
    }
    </style>
    <defs>
        <g id="digit" style="fill-rule:evenodd; stroke:#FFFFFF; stroke-width:0.25; stroke-opacity:1; stroke-linecap:butt; stroke-linejoin:miter;">
            <polygon id="a" points=" 10, 10  20, 0  80, 0  90, 10  80, 20  20, 20" />
            <polygon id="b" points=" 90, 10 100, 20 100, 80  90, 90  80, 80  80, 20" />
            <polygon id="c" points=" 90, 90 100,100 100,160  90,170  80,160  80,100" />
            <polygon id="d" points=" 90,170  80,180  20,180  10,170  20,160  80,160" />
            <polygon id="e" points=" 10,170  0,160  0,100  10, 90  20,100  20,160" />
            <polygon id="f" points=" 10, 90  0, 80  0, 20  10, 10  20, 20  20, 80" />
            <polygon id="g" points=" 10, 90  20, 80  80, 80  90, 90  80,100  20,100" />
        </g>
    </defs>
    <use href="#digit" x="0" y="0" id="digit1" />
    <use href="#digit" x="120" y="0" id="digit2" />
    <use href="#digit" x="300" y="0" id="digit3" />
    <use href="#digit" x="420" y="0" id="digit4" />
    <use href="#digit" x="600" y="0" id="digit5" />
    <use href="#digit" x="720" y="0" id="digit6" />
</svg>
```

This is pretty simple, but doesn't give us the ability to target individual polygons in each `<use>`. To do that, we can only really turn to one other shadow DOM penetrator, and that's CSS variables.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="900px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 900 200" xml:space="preserve">

    <style type='text/css'>
        :root {
            --a: red;
            --b: red;
            --c: red;
            --d: red;
            --e: red;
            --f: red;
            --g: red;
        }
        
        #digit2 {
            --a: white;
            --b: white;
        }
        
        #digit3, #digit4 {
            --g: white;
        }
        
        #digit5, #digit6 {
            --e: white;
        }
        
    </style>
    <defs>
        <g id="digit" style="fill-rule:evenodd; stroke:#FFFFFF; stroke-width:0.25; stroke-opacity:1; stroke-linecap:butt; stroke-linejoin:miter;">
            <polygon id="a" points=" 10, 10  20, 0  80, 0  90, 10  80, 20  20, 20" fill="var(--a)" />
            <polygon id="b" points=" 90, 10 100, 20 100, 80  90, 90  80, 80  80, 20" fill="var(--b)"/>
            <polygon id="c" points=" 90, 90 100,100 100,160  90,170  80,160  80,100" fill="var(--c)"/>
            <polygon id="d" points=" 90,170  80,180  20,180  10,170  20,160  80,160" fill="var(--d)"/>
            <polygon id="e" points=" 10,170  0,160  0,100  10, 90  20,100  20,160" fill="var(--e)"/>
            <polygon id="f" points=" 10, 90  0, 80  0, 20  10, 10  20, 20  20, 80" fill="var(--f)"/>
            <polygon id="g" points=" 10, 90  20, 80  80, 80  90, 90  80,100  20,100" fill="var(--g)"/>
        </g>
    </defs>
    <use href="#digit" x="0" y="0" id="digit2" />
    <use href="#digit" x="120" y="0" id="digit2" />
    <use href="#digit" x="300" y="0" id="digit3" />
    <use href="#digit" x="420" y="0" id="digit4" />
    <use href="#digit" x="600" y="0" id="digit5" />
    <use href="#digit" x="720" y="0" id="digit6" />
</svg>
```

Above, each polygons `fill` is set to a variable with a specific name - polygon a uses variable `--a` as its fill. Then, we use the fact that variables pierce the shadow DOM, and override the variable values on the individual use statements to get the desired effect. As these are just CSS variables, they'll work with any CSS property in modern browsers.

To answer the sub-question, `is there an easier way to do this?` - I would personally have the SVG represent just the one digit and have JS instance it repeatedly, assuming it's on a webpage and your goal is an animated clock. That way you can manipulate the polygons without the shadow DOMs encapsulation being directly in your way.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response! Was a huge help!